# How do Interpreted Languages Declare and Reference Variables?

Tags: python, variables, scripting, compilation

Let's take some simple pyhton code for instance:

```
var = 10
print(var)
```

I was wondering when and how `var` here would be both declared and referenced. I'm currently working on my own Lisp-inspired scripting language in C++ where this would be the equivalent code:

```
(def var 10)
(print var)
```

The language is broken down into three pieces: a **tokenizer**, a '**compiler**', and an **executor**.

Here `(def var 10)` is more so a 'compile' time construct that emplaces a new variable to the virtual machine with the key-value of "var". After this, the `(def...)` function is transformed into an initializer that re-initializes its variable when executed in the **execution** stage. `(print var)` then emplaces a pointer to "var" to its parameter-list as part of **compilation**, which again executes in the **execution** stage. Essentially upon reaching the end of its compilation, the execution has all its data set and requires no additional 'runtime' searches to attain the data it requires.

So in reality `(def...)` plays no part in the actual execution stage, but rather only its compilation. This leads to a bit of an inconsistency in structure, as all other functions are executed at, well, execution.

How do other interpreted languages tackle this problem? Would python declare "var" when it reaches `var = 10` at runtime and then dynamically locate and tie in a pointer to "var" upon executing `print(var)`? What are the benefits of establishing variable declarations in that manner, or perhaps should the design inconsistency be embraced for the entailed improvement in performance due to the reduced language runtime search?

Comment: This question might be better suited for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com rather than stack overflow

Comment: Thank you, I'll post it there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At module level python maintains a dictionary of variables. `.py` files are compiled into byte code when loaded and then the byte code adds "var" to that dictionary at runtime. Using this dictionary directly

```
>>> var
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'var' is not defined
>>> globals()["var"] = 10
>>> var
10
```

Functions are different. Python uses integer indexed slots for local variables, not a dictionary. When a function is compiled, variables that are assigned in the function are considered local and are converted to indexes in this slot table.

```
>>> def foo():
...     var = 10
... 
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (10)
              2 STORE_FAST               0 (var)
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

Notice that the `STORE_FAST 0` is storing in slot 0.

The reason python does things differently in these two cases is that it wants  other modules or the functions within a module to dynamically assign variables to the module any time they want. Class definitions are the same way. But functions are different. A new object is created to hold the function locals each time a function is executed. There is no easy way to get to that object from outside the function and its really not useful to have this external assignment feature.

So these are two examples in python itself. Be dynamic but a bit slower or be static and a bit faster. What's better for you is up to the goals you have for your langauge.